# Selecting data interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has date and id column. How can I select id's of 7 days interval?

My data is:

```
date            id 
2013-07-01      11
2013-07-02      22
2013-07-03      33
2013-07-04      33
2013-07-05      44  
2013-07-06      44      
2013-07-07      45  
2013-07-08      46  
2013-07-09      47
2013-07-10      48
2013-07-11      48
2013-07-12      49
2013-07-13      50
2013-07-14      51
2013-07-15      52
2013-07-16      52
2013-07-17      53
2013-07-18      53
2013-07-19      54
```

What I want is:

```
date            id
2013-07-01      11
2013-07-08      46
2013-07-15      52
```

Thanks

Comment: edited. I need a week interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT date,id FROM table1 GROUP BY WEEK(`date`, 1)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b128c/1

Comment: `date_sub` subtracts the interval from the date, it is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

the group by does not do the trick with (any) sql - ok mysql does - others wont allow this

```
SELECT date,id FROM table1 GROUP BY WEEK(`date`, 1)
```

would result in something like error: id is not part of group by ....

if you group by a col1 and not by col2  the database does not know what value you want for col2.

MySql seems to assume "if i do not group by others, take the smallest or first in databsse order'

If - and only if - you want the first (!) result - or what ever MySql decides to use for your missing 2nd grouping element, you are ok.

explanation:

assume this:

```
 CREATE TABLE table1
        (`id` int, `val` int );

 INSERT INTO table1
            (`id`, `val`)
    VALUES 
    (1,99), --'!!!!'
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (1,4),
    (1,2),
    (2,1),
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,1),
    (4,1)

;
```

See - please, there a 6 rows with 'id'=1, two with id '2' others unique

```
select id, val  FROM table1 GROUP BY id
```

evaluates to:

```
ID  VAL
1   99
2   1
3   1
4   1
```

this is only - probably - what you want and if it is a date you have a chance(!) the it will be what you want

to get a valid (without database intepret) result set you will have to use:

```
select id, some_aggregation_function(val) from table1 group by id
```

where aggregation is min, max or so.

the is some thing like :

```
select id, val  FROM table1 a 
where (id,val)=(select id, min(val) from table1 b where a.id=b.id)
```

if you want the minimum ....